# Rails Stylesheets on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stylesheet

On my local machine, when I view my Rails App, my stylesheets are successfully linked at `/assets/stylesheets/` but on Heroku, it is changed to `/stylesheets/` presumably in the `public` directory and does not work!  How do I get my stylesheets to move to `public/stylesheets` on compilation?

**EDIT:**

File directory after `rake assets:precompile`

```
app
  assets
    stylesheets
      application.css
      application.min.css
      home.css
      home.css.scss
      home.min.css
      scaffolds.css
      scaffolds.css.scss
      scaffolds.min.css
      startups.css
      startups.css.scss
public
  assets
    application-3701cb84bbc3c20d5a7ec1aac608fbdb.js
    application-3701cb84bbc3c20d5a7ec1aac608fbdb.js.gz
    application-f7ff7ad51f3528ccca1b5c7f2d5b5915.css
    application-f7ff7ad51f3528ccca1b5c7f2d5b5915.css.gz
    manifest-ad3babc6c84cc0b38f1a98eb594b8235.json
    rails-afd7b40a0142ed24738b640e78388de4.png
```

Here is my stylesheet link in `application.html.haml`:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "flat-ui", "home.min", media: "all"
```

`gem flatui-rails` is in my Gemfile and `*= require flat-ui` is in my `application.css` file.

**EDIT 2:**

Cleared my `public/assets` folder, added `public/assets/*` to my `.gitignore` and pushed to my Heroku repo.  During slug compilation Heroku ran the asset pipline and made `/assets/application-b2c82b0573602f3a368a26f36b99542b.css` which is also linked in the source code of my site, but the styles don't load and I get `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` when I try to navigate to the style sheet... Now what?

Here's my `application.html.haml`:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title StartupCrawler
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  = yield
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Michael, I before you push to heroku try:

`rake assets:precompile`

This will precompile them in the public folder so that they can be served to Heroku. Let me know if that didn't work.

Also, make sure the following line exists in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then of course

`git push heroku master`

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this is a step in the right direction, but it's still not working.  I added details about my configuration in the original post.  I have a suspicion I've done something wrong in my `application.html.haml` style link

Comment: After changing my `stylesheet_link_tag "flat-ui", "home.min", media: "all"` to `stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"` Heroku almost linked to a valid stylesheet, but it gave `/assets/application-4cd3d6fa233d3d69d4eb5f32c3ca36b5.css` as a link which was none of the precompiled assets that I have in my folders

Comment: Can you post your application.html.haml?
Also run `heroku logs` and post that output.

Comment: Added my `application.html.haml` and an update.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured it out... had to change `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/production.rb`

Comment: remove <%console%> if you added it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in compiled assets into Git, first read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#plugin-injection-in-rails-4

You can either add this gem

> gem 'rails_12factor'

or add this gem specifically

> rails_serve_static_assets

or manually change the config in `config/environments/production.rb`

> config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: Somebody made a gem just to change *one config variable?* Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Rails: The programming framework for people who don't like to program.