# Getting a jquery plugin (sidr) to work with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get this jQuery sidr plugin to work with my rails project on codecademy but its just not working.

Here's the page deployed:

https://tranquil-forest-7907.herokuapp.com/

Notice the upper left icon for the menu, doesnt appear instantly, and when you click on it, the menu doesn't properly show up.

**The weird part is that the menu appears properly (but the icon still loads slow) in the codecademy browser.**

It should look something like this:

https://stories-rails.herokuapp.com/

Here are some files:

layout application.html.erb:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stories</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<%= yield %>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        Developed by Satchel French
    </div>
  </div> 

<!-- javascript --> 
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
</body>
</html>
```

the menu stylesheet (sidr-dark.css)

```
    .sidr{display:none;position:absolute;position:fixed;top:0;height:100%;z-index:999999;width:260px;overflow-x:none;overflow-y:auto;font-family:"Roboto",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:19px;background:#000;color:#fff; font-weight:100;}
.sidr .sidr-inner{padding:0 0 15px}
.sidr .sidr-inner>p{margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px}
.sidr.right{left:auto;right:-260px}
.sidr.left{left:-260px;right:auto}
.sidr p{font-size:15px;margin:0 0 12px}
.sidr p a{color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9)}.sidr>p{margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px}
.sidr ul{display:block;margin:0 0 15px;padding:0;}
.sidr ul li{display:block;margin:10px;line-height:48px}
.sidr ul li:hover {background:#191919; margin: 10px;}
.sidr ul li a,.sidr ul li span{padding:0 40px;display:block;text-decoration:none;color:#fff}
```

and the home.html.erb:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- menu -->
    <div id="sidr">
  <!-- Your content -->
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- start page -->
   <div class="window main">
     <div class="container">
       <!-- menu button -->
       <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"><%= image_tag('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/z2d/stories/menu-white.svg',class:'icon-menu', alt:'open', width:'24px') %></a>
       <!-- content -->
       <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"> 
            <h1 class="headline"> Satchel and Travel </h1>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary sharp btn-lg" href="#" role="button"> Learn more </a> </p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <!-- home -supporting -->
  <div class="window-support">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="headline">Lets write about the moments.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- home secondary -->
  <div class="secondary">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- secondary support -->
  <div class="window-support">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="headline">Interested?</h2>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary sharp btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Adventure</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Any help at all is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Satchel

[image: picture of the same code running on codecademy;s browser]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074170/rails-stylesheets-on-heroku

This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your page with the one in https://stories-rails.herokuapp.com/ it seems to be missing some css configurations and/or the class definitions:

for the div sidr you would want to add the following styles for the menu to appear attached to the left side:

- position:fixed
- background-color:#ccc
- width: 240px

For the list items there isn't that much layout config done... this is why they appear "raw" there.

please have a look on the following classes from your reference website (to start with):

- .menu
- .menu ul
- ol, ul
- .menu li a

The class `menu` seem to be missing from your `div` definitions and from your loaded css files, You might have missed a css file from the plug-in (I'm not familiar with sidr, but this would be a fair guess).

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but no luck. It works 100% on the browser in codecademy but just not in heroku. (and im updating). Maybe somthing to do with the stylesheet tag?

Comment: my tests were in firefox and it was not working without some css twining. Did you try what matt elf said? it really looks like there is a missing class in your divs

Comment: I tried! But even the code on the sidr website says to just <div id="sidr"> for the javscript I believe. I tried using both for id and class simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is using `.sidr` but you aren't adding the class to the HTML.
Try changing `<div id="sidr">` to `<div class="sidr">`.